# How to add a Service Reference to a Portable Class Library project targeting Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I am seeing a strange behavior and wonder if I am doing something wrong or this is just how it is. When using a PCL, I target Windows Phone 7. At that point, I can add a Service Reference. Change the target to Windows Phone 8. At that point, I can no longer add a Service Reference.

Is there a way to add a Service Reference to a PCL project targeting WP8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to answer my own question, here. No. There is no way. To solve this problem I turn to interface-based design patterns where I can pass the service to the library.